# pgfplots with gnuplot

Tags: pgfplots, pdftex, gnuplot

I got a problem with latex implementing a gnuplot code. I use PdfLatex with argument "--enable-write18".

The following code should works with the first commented-out line `%plot 'data.dat' u 1:2;`, but it does not work with `%plot 'data.dat' u 1:(f(\$2))`. The proposed solution `plot 'data.dat' u 1:(f(\string$2));` cannot handle the `nan` values in the `data.dat`.
How can I fix this? And is there an opportunity to execute `gnuplot` code in `TeX` from an extern file? Maybe this could solve the problem and I could use `$` instead of `\$` or `\string$`?

It should look like the second picture.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
time    w1  e1  w2  e2
1   3019    40  nan nan
2   3045    34  nan nan
3   3100    50  3104    24
4   3500    13  3498    90
5   3800    90  3803    12
6   NaN NaN 3980    43
7   NaN NaN 3985    80
8   3810    10  3988    34
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
compat=newest,
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
ymin=2900,
ymax=4400]


\addplot gnuplot
[raw gnuplot,id=bal,mark=none,very thick]{
set datafile missing 'NaN';
set xrange  [1:8];
set yrange [3000:4500];
f(x)=x;
plot 'data.dat' u 1:(f(\string$2));
%plot 'data.dat' u 1:2;
%plot 'data.dat' u 1:(f(\$2))
    };

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: bad]

[image: good]

Comment: I've had better luck with asymptote's graph plotting capabilities. It is a bit harder to use (but much more flexible), while it integrates much better with LaTeX fonts and such.

Comment: Is it possible to convert a column (with a function of raw data) with asymptote?

Comment: @vonbrand: PGFPlots integrates perfectly with LaTeX fonts and such, gnuplot is merely used as a number cruncher in the background here.

Comment: does anyone have an idea how to fix the first picture?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what `pcygni.txt` file is and I got no output from that, but your main problem is `\$` is a command to choose fonts and typeset a `$` but (I think) you want to pass a `$` to gnuplot so it is the wrong sort of quoting.

this runs without error although probably isn't the plot you want.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
time    w1  e1  w2  e2
1   3019    40  nan nan
2   3045    34  nan nan
3   3100    50  3104    24
4   3500    13  3498    90
5   3800    90  3803    12
6   nan nan 3980    43
7   nan nan 3985    80
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
compat=newest,
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
ymin=2900,
ymax=4400]


\addplot gnuplot
[raw gnuplot,id=bal,mark=none,very thick]{
set xrange  [1:8];
set yrange [3000:4500];
f(x)=3600;
plot 'data.dat' u 1:(f(\string$2));
plot 'data.dat' u 1:2
    };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: now the code compiles, just the "nan" values gnuplot cannot handle